# Best way to return data with buttons/events in Kivy

Tags: python, events, button, kivy

I have a function

```
 def myfunc():
     sum = 2+2 #4
     widget = Button(id="sumButton", text="Normal binding to a property change")
     widget.bind(state=self.callback)
```

The callback function:

```
def callback(self, eventObjetct):
    print "id: ", eventObject.id
```

This will print:

> id: sumButton

how can I return sum to the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not want to pass *sum* to *callback* method using *on_state* property change because the method, callback will be invoked twice - once when you press the button, and once when you release the button. Therefore, you want to use on_press or on_release event with lambda function to pass sum to callback method.

The best way depends on how many items you want to pass to the method. The example below illustrates two possibilities - lambda and partial functions.

## Overload method __init__

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(DemoBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

> We overload the method __init__() so as to add widgets and to define
>   their behavior. One should not forget to call super in order to
>   implement the functionality of the original class being overloaded.
>   Also note that it is good practice not to omit the **kwargs while
>   calling super, as they are sometimes used internally.

By running __init__ we're passing **kwargs up the object hierarchy and also re-defining __init__ which would normally run the initialization of the parent class. super is used to allow us to pass **kwargs and run the parent __init__ without an explicit call to the parent class. In this case, BoxLayout inherits from Layout; without a super call you're overriding the parent class.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from functools import partial


class DemoBox(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DemoBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.myFunc()

    def myFunc(self):
        sum = 2 + 2
        btn1 = Button(id="summButton", text="Normal binding to a property change")
        btn1.bind(state=partial(self.callback, x=sum))
        btn2 = Button(text="Bind on_press/on_release event")
        btn2.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.on_press(x=sum))
        self.add_widget(btn1)
        self.add_widget(btn2)

    def callback(self, obj, value, x):
        print("callback: x=", x)

    def on_press(self, x):
        print("on_press: x=", x)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Passing Arguments to Method - Using Lambda & Partial Functions"

    def build(self):
        return DemoBox()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: This is good, now how does the keyword super() interact with the __init__ function?

Comment: I have added explanations for overloading thed method __init__